# How do I implement foreach loop in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Implementing a for loop in clojure seems to be easy, but how can I implement a foreach statement that reads each element in the list(vector) and does something?

like this...

```
(foreach i list expression)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about [`map`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/map): `(map (fn [i] …) list)`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just replace `for` with `doseq` and you're all set. Don't use `map`, which is just as lazy as `for`.

Comment: More precisely: (doseq [i list] expression)

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I figured my answer was sufficient since he already knows how to use `for`, but of course people may wind up reading this who don't.

Answer (score 0):

[`map`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/map) is the functional equivalent of `foreach`, whereas [`doseq`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doseq) is for imperative programming with side-effects.

`map` takes a function `f` and a seqable collection `coll` and returns the lazily-evaluated result of applying `f` to each element in the collection.

#### Example:

```
(map inc [1 2 3 4])
=> (2 3 4 5)

(map (fn [x] (* x 2)) [1 2 3 4])
=> (2 4 6 8)

(map dec (take 5 (range)))
=> (-1 0 1 2 3)
```